# read text from a specific webpage and save it in a variable with javascript

Tags: javascript

my question is simple but cant get through it,, please some help guys,,please... i want to read text from a specific webpage..the text is inside the body and inside a span class called string ..  and then i want to save the readen text in a variable...

i m using javascript for this...in general if i want to read text and save it variable lets say called json i would use smthng like that..

```
  var json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('container').innerHTML);
```

but now on my question above how can i do that?

Comment: Assuming you mean a remote page - If the page is on *your domain* use an Ajax Request, otherwise you will need to use a proxy script on your server to download the page in order to get around same-origin restrictions

Comment: You can try to open a website in the iframe and then get its content with Javascript. Keyowrds: ``contentWindow``, ``iframe``

Answer (score 0):

If the page is on the same domain as your website you can use ajax request as you did and then parse the innerHTML as element and go to your span by tag name or class name or whatever specify it.

To create html main element from the response (innerHTML) use document.createElement(x);

Comment: guys thank you so much!!! 4 the replies. and the answer of course.. reallly appreciated... but look i was thinking 4 smthn like that using jquery  using the json variable of the payload $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'http://mypage/page', data: { someVariable: 'foo' }, success: function(response) { console.log(response); } }); were inside the function response i will have the var json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('container').innerHTML); but i m confused 1st with the suntax and 2nd to read the specific span class string

Answer (score 0):

try to use a **scraper** script to retreive the page content .

you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup python package to do it